# Show information near mouse pointer problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dojo

I hava available JQuery and Dojo and I need to display info near mouse pointer (like tooltip). To be more clear, I have Dojo slider and while user sliding I need to show around mouse like tooltip some info ( hours and minutes ). How to solve this ? Is there any already done functions for this in Dojo or Jquery or JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

**JQUERY UI POSITIONING**

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position

This is the perfect api to get your job done.Add a label in page in body any where initially hidden and
in onchange event simply position it along your mouse pointer and with the updated text content.Thats what i did.

Make sure it is absolute position

```
$(document).mousemove(function(ev){
```

$("#position4").position({
    my: "left bottom",
    of: ev,
    offset: "3 -3",
    collision: "fit"
  });
});

This code will actually add the reference div on mouse position every time but you can customize it as your requirement